# Meteor route not registering

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, meteor, bson

I've included relevant snippets of 3 files in this issue below...

```
routes.js https://bpaste.net/show/657823862ec3
publications.js https://bpaste.net/show/68f368befc02
institution.html https://bpaste.net/show/dab1e7caf0bf
```

Not sure why the route isn't registering. `Exception in defer callback: Error: Oh no! No route found for path: "/institution/W4TPyFfrZpSCErrKK`".

There is a doc in the 'institutions' collection in mongo that relates to this as seen below. Also, the collection is defined in my main js file via `Institutions = new Meteor.Collection('institutions');`

```
{
  "admin": "John Doe",
  "title": "MIT Bitcoin Club",
  "type": "Club",
  "school": "MIT",
  "description": "Bitcoin is a new technology that’s revolutionizing the transactional economy.",
  "members": [
    "John Doe",
    "Joe Clan"
  ],
  "_id": "W4TPyFfrZpSCErrKK"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
this.route('institution'), {
  ...
}
```

you should have:

```
this.route('institution', {
  ...
});
```

Comment: Yeah, got it thereafter